# Как поставить и убрать фокус с UITextField? При чём здесь First Responder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextfield

Как активировать, поставить фокус на `UITextField` и в нужный момент убрать, скрыв клавиатуру? Как с этим связано понятие ***First Responder***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Как реализовать?

Допустим, у Вас есть какой-нибудь `UITextField *textField`, тогда переместить на него фокус и открыть клавиатуру можно так:

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

А убрать фокус и скрыть клавиатуру так:

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Если нужно обрабатывать нажатие кнопки `Return` на клавиатуре, то в контроллере понадобится реализовать протокол `UITextFieldDelegate` и установить контроллер как делегат текстового поля. Тогда нажатие кнопки можно обработать таким методом:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

---

### Как это работает?

iOS приложения получают события, которые обрабатываются соответствующими ***Responder***, *ответчиками*. Это объекты классов-наследников от `UIResponder`, большинство контроллеров и элементов интерфейса от него наследуются.

Чтобы не было путаницы, все ответчики всегда выстроены в последовательность, называемую ***Responder chain***. При этом, самый первый из них может быть выделен визуально, показывая на себе фокус, как `UITextField` с подсветкой и открытой клавиатурой. Но не обязательно: после вызова `resignFirstResponder` первым ответчиком становится контроллер, и визуально это не проявляется.

Например, в проигрывателе при реализации фичи *"shake to shuffle"* (встряхнуть смартфон чтобы перемешать плейлист) в роли первого ответчика как раз выступает `view controller`, который перехватывает соответствующее событие редактирует плейлист.

Узнать об этой теме подробнее можно здесь: [Understanding Event Handling, Responders, and the Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/understanding_event_handling_responders_and_the_responder_chain).